Medusa Js v1 - how do i default the customer to a region store
Hi if anyone have any input on this, will greatly appreicated.
I am using the maxmind database but it seems like it not setting the region based on the ip address.
This is my code in the middleware.
async function getCountryCode(
  request: NextRequest,
  regionMap: Map<string, Region | number>
) {
  try {
    let countryCode
    let ipAddress: string | null = request.headers.get("x-forwarded-for") || null;

    if (ipAddress) {
      // The x-forwarded-for can contain multiple IP addresses; use the first one.
      ipAddress = ipAddress.split(",")[0].trim()
    }
    console.log(ipAddress)
    // Fetch country code using the extracted IP address
    const maxmindDBCountryCode = await fetch(${BACKEND_URL}/store/ip-lookup, {
      headers: {
        "x-real-ip": ipAddress ?? "",
      },
    })
    const data = await maxmindDBCountryCode.json()

    const urlCountryCode = request.nextUrl.pathname.split("/")[1]?.toLowerCase()

    // Prioritize country code from IP lookup if available and valid
    if (data.country_code && regionMap.has(data.country_code.toLowerCase())) {
      countryCode = data.country_code.toLowerCase()
    }
    // If a country code is specified in the URL and valid, use it
    if (urlCountryCode && regionMap.has(urlCountryCode)) {
      countryCode = urlCountryCode
    }
    // If no valid country code from above, use the default region
    if (!countryCode && regionMap.has(DEFAULT_REGION)) {
      countryCode = DEFAULT_REGION
    }
    // If still no country code, use the first available region in the map
    if (!countryCode && regionMap.keys().next().value) {
      countryCode = regionMap.keys().next().value
    }

    return countryCode
  } catch (error) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      console.error(
        "Middleware.ts: Error getting the country code. Did you set up regions in your Medusa Admin and define a NEXT_PUBLIC_MEDUSA_BACKEND_URL environment variable?"
      )
    }
  }
}


So what is the error? At which point does the script fail or returns the wrong value? You've already some debug code in-place, I suggest expanding those to all if-branches in order to evaluate the result or debug the NodeJS process itself at step through it.

Hi @JimmyBlu, thanks for the comment.
Apologise i wasnt clear, I realise that its able to get the Ip address of the client, but the middleware layer was called a couple of times, towards the end its using the App server's IP address.
I am not well verse in the medusa stack and still learning on it. I thought I expand the question here on stackoverflow as I am not getting a response on discord.
